# Alignment of dynamic views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, view, android-xml

I want the alignment of the editext and the imageviewin the same horizontal line but I am getting the imageview below the edittext.

> main fragment code

```
 final LinearLayout lnrView = (LinearLayout) 
 child.findViewById(R.id.lnrView);
                Button btnad = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.btnad);
                btnad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        lnrView.addView(newedittext());
                        lnrView.addView(newImageview(getActivity()));
                    }
                });
```

neweditext method

```
  private View newedittext() {
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    int id = 0;
    editText.setId(id);
    editText.setTextSize(14);
    editText.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    editText.setMaxEms(2);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    return editText;
}
```

> newImageview method

```
 public ImageView newImageview(Context context) {
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
    int id = 0;
    imgView.setId(id);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_close_red));
    return imgView;
}
```

> main fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="add" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

when i click the Add button an edittext and  Imageview is created dynamically and my output screen look like below

[image]

i want the `imageview` and the `edittext` in the same line. can anyone help me.

when i add "Horizontal" this is the output

[image]

this my expected result

[image]

Comment: Your `lnrView` has `vertical` orientation

Comment: add android:orientation="horizontal" to your inner view

Comment: @ADM not getting the expected result, i have updated the question by adding orientation = horizontal

Comment: @Shaishav by changing the orientation to horizontal didnt help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add first a `Horizontal` `Linearlayout` in Your `lnrView` than add `EditText` and `Imageview`

Try this

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            layout.addView(newedittext());
            layout.addView(newImageview(MainActivity.this));

            lnrView.addView(layout);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the result by using orientation horizontal, and that is not i want,

Comment: @AmruthaSaj check updated ans it woking fine in my device

Comment: @AmruthaSaj happy to help you enjoy codding

Answer (score 0):

Or simpler use

> `ListView`

with

> `ArrayAdapter`

where you define you own layout (`EditText` and `button`)

There is better way to manage add and remove lines.

Also you have all `EditTexts` in one array and you can do your logic simpler.