# How to set a line break after a set of EditText which have been dynamically created?

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to show few EditText field just like n*n Matrix. I am creating these EditText field dynamically.

Problem is all my EditText field prints in the same line horizontally.
I wanted to know is there anything like "System.out.println();" in Android Studio!

Note: I want this line break in between Views, not in between Text, so \n doesn't work here!

**This is my activity_main.xml file**,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--EditText Fields going to be here!-->

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**And Here's my MainActivity.java file**

```
package com.ridi.magicfield;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int a;

    private static EditText magicField, ainput;
    private static Button btn;

    private static LinearLayout child_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        child_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_layout);


        ainput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = Integer.parseInt(ainput.getText().toString());

                child_layout.removeAllViews();
                createMatrixInputField();
            }
        });

    }

    private void createMatrixInputField() {
        int p = 1;
        for (int t = 1; t <= a; t++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {

                magicField = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                magicField.setId((p));
                magicField.setHint("et-" + (Integer.toString(p)));
                magicField.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                child_layout.addView(magicField);

                p++;

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here's my output screen. I want et-3 and et-4 to go to next line.
Is there anyone who can help please...
[Output Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQUEH.png)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648322/alignment-of-dynamic-views

Comment: Use margin for views.

Comment: you have to create linear layouts(horizontal) dynamically and add those layouts to parent linear layout (vertical). as you are creating editext and then add you editexts to that linear layout

Comment: This Linear Layout is already horizontal, and I tried with a parent layout of vertical orientation, but i still couldn't make it work. Can anyone give me a demo code on what u guys are trying to indicate..

Comment: Well, creating a Horizontal Layout DYNAMICALLY actually solved my problem ...
Thanks to all of you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` for n*n matrix pattern

```
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
          TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
          TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new 
          TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT 
          ,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          row.setLayoutParams(lp);

          for(int j = 0; j < noOfColumns; j++) {
             EditText et = new EditText(this);
             //Extra properties goes here...
             et.setText("Your text");
             row.addView(et,j);
           }
        tableLayout.addView(row,i);
     }
```

Comment: The problem got solved actually by creating a horizontal linear layout dynamically! 
But Now another problem arose. 
Previously I was able to set unique ID and Hint for my EditText Fields. But now it just updates once. 
So I will give it a try with using Tablelayout trick also... 
Thanks for suggestions...

Comment: It works great for setting unique id and hint.
Thanks again :) @itsmysterybox